# Oracle SQL how to select (or include data) if it doesn't exist sometimes?

Tags: sql, oracle

When I select data in a view,
I will get the data in most cases like this:

```
Referred Job_Status     Jobs
OPS      DISPATCHED     9
OPS      NOT_DISPATCHED 3
```

But sometimes the data doesn't exist and I only get this:

```
Referred Job_Status     Jobs
OPS      DISPATCHED     9
```

When it doesn't exist I still want to show it as zero:

```
Referred Job_Status     Jobs
OPS      DISPATCHED     9  
OPS      NOT_DISPATCHED 0
```

Sorry I'm having a Friday morning where I can't think straight.

Comment: Share the SQL of the view so that we can help you

Comment: What's your source table for job_status? and how do we know which ones of those to include?  You basically start with that table and left join it to the table having your refereed and jobs that you're counting.

Answer (score 2):

**you can try like this:**

```
with main as (
select 'OPS' Referred ,'DISPATCHED' Job_Status FROM DUAL
UNION
select 'OPS' Referred ,'NOT_DISPATCHED ' Job_Status FROM DUAL
)
SELECT
MAIN.Referred ,MAIN.Job_Status , NVL(SUB.JOBS,0) JOBS
FROM MAIN LEFT OUTER JOIN YOUR_VIEW SUB ON  MAIN.REFERRED=SUB .REFERRED 
                                        AND MAIN.Job_Status =SUB.Job_Status ;
```

Comment: Thanks XqBert and Ersin using a combination of both your answers I will have to create a table first of all my Referred values with a row for each dispatched and not dispatched and follow the code as an example.